# Directly refer to a function in PeerJS

Tags: javascript, function, webrtc, peerjs

For a project I'm currently using a Javascript library called peerJS for some webRTC stuff. I had my code build like this

```
$(function(){
    peer.on('open', function(id) {
        //stuff to be done
    });

    //more functions like  this
});
```

But as I have to load this when the DOM is ready and the code became quite a mess i decided to make a seperate function for it.

```
$(function(){
    peer.on('open', function(id) {
        peerOpen(id);
    });

    //more functions like this
});

function peerOpen(id){
    //stuff to be done
};

//more functions like this
```

but this seems somewhat comprehensive so I tried this:

```
$(function() {
    peer.on('open', peerOpen());

    //more functions like this
});

function peerOpen(id){
    //stuff to be done
};

//more functions like this
```

But that isn't working for me, am i doing something simple wrong or is the thing that I try to do just completely impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    peer.on('open', peerOpen);

    //more functions like this
});

function peerOpen(id){
    //stuff to be done
};
```

You just need to pass in the function reference! In your example, you were calling the function.